# Using `find` for multiple file types and replacing strings in found files

Tags: bash, recursion, sed, find

I'm trying to recursively find files of multiple types, and replace a certain string in each of the files found. But when I run the script, it only finds files of one single type.

The command line I'm using is this

```
find . -name '*.tcl' -o -name '*.itcl' -o -name '*.db' -exec sed -i 's/abc/cba/g' {} +
```

Every time I run the command above, it only finds files of type `.db`. When I run it with a single file type, it works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to group the `-names *` part with `()` like that :

Moreover, it's better (from my experience) to run `sed -i` only on files that match the pattern, so :

```
find . \( -name '*.tcl' -o -name '*.itcl' -o -name '*.db' \) -exec sed -i '/abc/s/abc/cba/g' {} +
```

Comment: And how do i tell it to not look in a specific folder?

Comment: Like that : `! -path '*/folder/*'`

Answer (score 1):

Below command will search for either txt or log files and replace the source string with the target string.

```
 find . -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.log"|xargs perl -pe 's/source/target/g'
```

you can do the replace ment by adding an -i in the perl statement as below:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.log"|xargs perl -pi -e 's/source/target/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
find . -regex ".*\.\(tcl\|itcl\|db\)" -exec sed -i 's/abc/cba/g' {} +
```

This is more compact, and you do not have to mess around with OR and grouping the logical operations.